# Bluetooth pairing hangs up the system in debian

Tags: linux, debian, usb, bluetooth

Whenever I try to pair bluetooth in debian using bluetooth-agent command, the system hangs up and I am unable to do anything with it. When I ask for access from my remote laptop it gives the message of Authorizing xx:xx:xx:xx device and again nothing happens. Just when I remove the bluetooth dongle from my usb port the system returns to the normal state saying agent-released. I have not installed gnome on the system. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had strange problems with bluetooth pairing and obex data transfer on debian. I was actually trying to upload photos from my Android phone at the time.

I installed the graphical bluetooth manager [blueman](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=blueman). This seemed to deal with the underlying system in a much saner way than other tools and everything started working properly.
I can't admit to fully resolving what the low-level problems were exactly, but hey, the outcome was good!